# Swedish text on php page

Tags: html

I am translating my webpage to swedish and it is no problem but on the only PHP page the Swedish language settings does not work

[www.havouza.com/index_sv.html](https://havouza.com/index_sv.html) working without problem
[www.havouza.com/contact_sv.php](https://havouza.com/contact_sv.php) dont work as you can see

The header is the same in both pages, only difference is the PHP part

```
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<meta http-equiv=“Content-Type” content=“text/html; charset=utf-8” />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: We can't help with PHP questions unless PHP is included. Likely it is something in the dup though.

Comment: ADyson where is a missing quote mark?

Comment: user3783243 I did not add the php code becuae its hardy that is a problem, its a PHPMailer scrips that works without a problem

Comment: Is it even properly stored in your database?

Comment: This is a charset problem. It might be in the php-file itself (as it is saved) or the DB-driver or how your DB is specified. Can you show us how you connect to your  DB in your PHP? Because it is fetched from a DB?

Comment: I solved it by using ASCII . Not much text so its ok

Comment: bestprogrammerintheworld  ikiK
Its pure html, no db involved. I am an old fart that use static pages

Comment: @AndersYuran your description of your problem references PHP as a static webpage but doesn't go into any details. Your comments then reference PHPMailer, which just further clouds the issue. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask